# How to extract return value from Thread in kotlin

Tags: multithreading, kotlin

Assume I have a function in which I send a http request and get the results. Obviously, I have some wait inside it:

```
fun getDocuments(): JsonObject {
        Thread {
            return@Thread functionToGetHttpResultAsJsonObject()
        }.start()
    }
```

What I need is to extract return value of functionToGetHttpResultAsJsonObject() into getDocuments() return value. But I get Unit instead my desired JsonObject. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: why to use thread if you are blocking the main thread with waiting for him to finish?

Comment: because functionToGetHttpResultAsJsonObject() is a global function. It is created before and need to remain unchanged

Comment: That doesn't explain why, if you want to block until it finishes and pass back its return value, you're running it in a separate thread instead of calling it directly (synchronously).

Answer (score 1):

Let's start that your request is a bit strange. You normally don't spin a thread to block the main thread waiting for it to finish. The main point of threads is to not do that, that said.

There is no simple way to pass information between threads.

If you want to wait for a thread to finish inside another thread you should call `.join()` instead of `.start()`

But that will not return anything. If you want to synchronize two threads. So one waits for the other to compute some data and get that data, one way to do it is to use a `BlockingQueue`

```
val queue = LinkedBlockingQueue<Int>()

Thread {
    println("concurrency ftw")
    Thread.sleep(1_000)
    println("finish sleeping!")
    queue.add(1)
}.start()

println("first")
println(queue.take())
```

Notice I'm using `.start()` here because I don't want to block the second Thread to do it's processing.

The main thread will block at the `.take` until someone adds some data.
At the same time, if the second thread arrived first to the `.add` it will also block until someone consumes that data.

At this point I also should mention that Kotlin has the concept of coroutines. They are very similar in concept to Go "channels" and I would advice to [look into those as well](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/coroutines/coroutines-basic-jvm.html).